# how to add underline below php value

Tags: php, html, css

Hello guys I am trying add a long line below my

```
<?php echo '$word'; ?>
```

and I am only getting a underlined word. What I want to get is like this:

```
Name of the Owner: SAMPLE NAME HERE                     Birthdate:
                  _____________________________________           ____________
```

Just like that and here my current code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="name" placeholder="" size="10" style='margin-right:.3em; border: none; border-color: transparent; pointer-events:none;text-decoration: underline;' value="<?php echo $fullname; ?>">
```

NOTE: Please don't mind the `in-line` CSS. Thanks guys!

Comment: isn't long line under the word and underline?

Comment: @AdrianPascua Are you trying to add underlining Text in an `<input>` field?

Comment: i want to have a default line after the Name of the Owner: . something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP does not support underline in string values. You can use CSS. Eg below:

```css
input {
  height:20px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: -2px 5px 0px -2px grey, 2px 5px 0px -2px grey;
}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a bottom border on the input. This way the underline will scale with the width

```
input {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    /* This is used to ensure the border is close to the text
       Adjust these values as needed. */
    padding-bottom: 0;
    /* Maybe a width here for a longer line past owner */
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not able to understand your problem
But I think this might be helpful

```
<?php echo "<u>". '$word' ."</u>"; ?>
```

This is enough to underline the string variable word